# Where does the archetype list come from in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

In IntelliJ IDEA, Select "File-->New Project-->Maven-->Next", then we will see a list of archetypes.

In terminal, if we input the command: mvn archetype:generate, we would find another list of archetypes.

The problem is that these two lists are different. I know the second list consists of "remote" and "local", but I've no idea where the first archetype list comes from.

In special, How can I choose "local" archetype from the first list? I installed my own archetype, but I can't find it in the first list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In special, How can I choose "local" archetype from the first list? I installed my own archetype, but I can't find it in the first list.

After applying

> "File-->New Project-->Maven-->Next"

Check "Create from Archetype" and click "Add Archetype" button

[image]

Fill in the archetype GAV coordinates and optionally the Repository if you had deployed your archetype to a Maven repository.

Next time you will create a new maven project in IDEA, your own archetype will appear in the archetypes list

Comment: thanks, it works! In addition, Can you explain what's the difference between these two lists?

Comment: Hard to say, you maybe using different Maven installation or  settings.xml

Comment: I used IDEA 13, local Maven which is maven-3.1.1, and the settings file:~/.m2/settings.xml